# MathJax renders strange in my post-edit page with AJAX post-preview functionality

Tags: ajax, math, mathjax

I have something like the StackOverflow's "Ask Question" page, where a text-box is used to put source markup code and, below, another text-box (non-editable) is used to render a preview of the post/question being typed.

Consider that my application not only lets me use a simple tiny markup language for my posts' content; it also provides me with the possibility to type math in it using [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/). But the syntax is simple Latex syntax (however this is not the problem, so do not let this thing bother you too much).

#### The problem

The problem is the following. The page is a little different from the StackOverflow's one because it uses ASP.NET with AJAX in order to call a server-side procedure that performs the markup language translation in HTML (this is my choice, I have the code server-side, there is no implementation in javascript of the markup translation code).

When the asynchronous script runs (every 10 secs), the non-editable text-box is re-filled with the translated markup. The Latex code as well is put there (no translation performed on it) and MathJax script is called everytime the AJAX procedure returns (so the latex code will be rendered after the markup language, this latex rendering happens client-side).

The problem is that, sometimes, rendered math is strange especially considering equation numberings. Numbers do increase every new AJAX call. I guess there must be a way to reset, completely, the status of the MathJax object instantiated in the page or whatever... Is there a way to reset MathJax?

I assume that AJAX here is the problem... Thankyou for your help, hope I was clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have loaded a configuration file that includes the AMSmath extension, you can use

```
MathJax.InputJax.TeX.resetEquationNumbers()
```

to reset the equation numbering and the labels used for `\ref` and `\eqref`.  If you want to start the numbering at a particular equation number, use

```
MathJax.InputJax.TeX.resetEquationNumbers(n)
```

where `n` is the starting number minus 1 (the default is 0).